# Difference between "goal" and "objective"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “goals” and “objectives”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48584/difference-between-goals-and-objectives)

For a work related thing (sales) I need to list *goals* and also list *objectives*. What are the differences?

Comment: Are you seriously saying your employer has asked you to make separate lists of *goals* and *objectives*? That sounds unlikely to me, but if so I really think you should ask the boss what exactly he wants in each list.

Comment: I asked an almost identical question yesterday. How odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In colloquial speech the two are interchangeable but for business purposes many people do make a distinction between the two.

During my studies for a degree in business administration I was taught that goals are somewhat fuzzier than objectives, e.g. "I want to sell more next year". On the other hand, objectives should be SMART (i.e. Specific, Measurable, Achievable, Realistic, and Timely), e.g. "Next year I want to increase sales by 10% before 31 December."

Keep in mind that in practice a goal can be made more concrete by defining the objectives that are needed to attain that goal. In other words, one goal can be supported by several objectives, and when all those specific objectives have been met you could claim that your goal has been reached.

Here's two websites that explain the difference in a bit more detail:

http://thebusinessplanblog.com/%E2%80%9Cgoals%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Cobjectives%E2%80%9D-know-the-difference-get-better-results/

http://www.differencebetween.net/business/difference-between-goals-and-objectives/

Comment: I think this is a good answer to a badly-phrased question. I suggest you copy it in to the later (better phrased) question which I've [flagged as a duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48584/difference-between-goals-and-objectives).

Answer (score 1):

I usually associate with *goals* my long-term aspirations or things I work toward. A *goal* may also be the expected result of some plan of action, with which I associate the word *objective*. But they’re synonyms, really.

I rarely hear someone enumerate their life “objectives,” but frequently hear them speak of their life “goals.” In this way, I’d expect *objective* to be used in the context of a particular task.